# Rewrite JavaScript function signature in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I've googled this with no success, and I can't find an answer in the docs.  In WebStorm how can I refactor the definition of a function to be assigned to a variable eg:

```
function foo(args) {

}
```

becomes

```
var foo = function(args) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no intention in current WebStorm versions for such transformation.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-12768 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.